# Record Shell output

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I wanted to know how to record all the input and output of my Ubuntu terminal.

Of course, I can use the `script` command but since I am using this in a shell script, it stops my script from going any further until I use the `exit` command and stop the recording.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of `script` and interactive shell. The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sh -i <<EOF
echo test
EOF
```

Capturing the input/output (works both in an interactive session and inside a script):

```
$ script -c ./script.sh 
Script started, file is typescript
sh$ echo test
test
sh$ exit
Script done, file is typescript
```

Result:

```
$ cat typescript 
Script started on 11 Apr 2014 10:23:13
sh$ echo test
test
sh$ exit

Script done on 11 Apr 2014 10:23:13
```